# How to create virtual environment on python3.x on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, proxy, virtualenv

I use college internet proxy.

running this command:

> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtual

I get error :

```
ags@enigma ~/code> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtual
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 555, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 753, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 230, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 832, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 918, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2
ags@enigma ~/code> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtual
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 555, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 753, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 230, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 832, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ags/code/virtual/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 918, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/ags/code/virtual/bin/python3 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

It shows

> OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

but I have configured proxy settings and Its working fine. 
Why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, https_proxy and http_proxy variables were not set in /etc/environment file.

> export http_proxy='http://myusr:mypswd@myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080'
>
> export https_proxy='https://myusr:mypswd@myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080'

did the job.